# App hangs and finally crashes, calling [NSView cursorUpdate:] n times

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, crash, stack-overflow

I have been seeing above mentioned crash upon clicking on return key or space bar, while i am editing my textfield. crash log has no reference to any line of my code.

```
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00007fff54c2fff8

VM Regions Near 0x7fff54c2fff8:
MALLOC_SMALL           00007f85ec000000-00007f85ee000000 [ 32.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--> STACK GUARD            00007fff51430000-00007fff54c30000 [ 56.0M] ---/rwx SM=NUL  stack guard for thread 0
Stack                  00007fff54c30000-00007fff55430000 [ 8192K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  thread 0

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff92b7b149 CGSLogTrace + 24
1   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff92b82d9d CGSGetCurrentCursorLocation + 125
2   com.apple.CoreGraphics          0x00007fff92bb417b CGSGetWindowMouseLocation + 73
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff96d3f3cd PScurrentmouse + 74
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff96d3f32c _NSCurrentMouseLocationInWindow + 71
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff96e8cbe5 -[NSWindow(NSCarbonExtensions) _findCursorForView:] + 94
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff96e8cb42 -[NSView cursorUpdate:] + 84
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff96e8ce17 forwardMethod + 125
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff96e8cb7b -[NSView cursorUpdate:] + 141
```

and same thing goes on forever. Can any one help me with this? thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: Is anything written to the console? It sounds like maybe something else in your app is corrupting memory, but it's not showing up until `cursorUpdate` runs.

Comment: No, console shows only app related logs nothing related to crash or memory corruption, basically nothing useful.

Comment: i hope you got this resolved

Comment: Not yet. i know app is entering infinite loop . but just could not stop .kindly share any thoughts which can help me solve this.

Comment: Did you have any luck resolving this?